# Import data from csv file as variable for code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to import a set of data from a CSV file to shorten my code in python,

Before I try to use the CSV file as a variable, I have confirmed the code is working as below:

```
csvone = pd.read_csv("csvone.csv")

data_a = csvone[csvone['IP Address'].str.contains(r'10.1\.')]
data_a["PCLOCATION"] = 'LOCATION_A'

data_b = csvone[csvone['IP Address'].str.contains(r'10.2\.')]
data_b["PCLOCATION"] = 'LOCATION_B'

data = [data_a, data_b]
result = pd.concat(data)

print(result)
```

The result of print(result) return all matched data and add another column named PCLOCATION.

But when I try to use a CSV file as variables it returns error when using the code below:

```
csvone = pd.read_csv("csvone.csv")
csvdata = pd.read_csv("csvdata.csv")

x = csvdata['IP']
z = csvdata['LOCATION']

pat = "|".join("^" + s.replace("." , r"\.") for s in x)
data = csvone[csvone['IP Address'].str.contains(x)]
data["PCLOCATION"] = (z)

print(data)
```

<strike>I get error TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'.</strike>  
By using code provided by @Timus, the unhashable error fixed.

The outcome is not as expected, seems like I am missing some part of the code that links the **IP** and **LOCATION** in the same row.

The current outcome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmHlU.png

The csv file I am using:

```
csvone = pd.DataFrame({
    "IP Address": ["10.1.100.123", "10.1.100.125", "10.2.120.128", "10.2.100.130","10.3.100.150", "10.10.200.168", "10.20.180.199"],
    "INFO": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
})

csvdata = pd.DataFrame({
    "IP": ["10.1.", "10.2.100.", "10.2.120.", "10.3.", "10.10.", "10.20."], 
    "LOCATION": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
})
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `df["LOCATION"] = (z)`? Assign the values in `csvdata["LOCATION"]` to the "LOCATION" column on `df`? Are you sure that `df` is a dataframe?

Comment: Hi aaossa, I have edited the post as I'm not sure is it a dataframe or not.

Comment: What's actually in the CSV?

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error? It might be a good idea to split compound expressions into multiple rows for debugging, to see exactly where the problem happens. (My guess is the `contains(x)`).

Comment: Hi @aaossa, On the `data["LOCATION"] = (z)` , I was trying to add a new column named **LOCATION** on **data** , and get values from **csvdata.csv's LOCATION column** and put it on (z)

Comment: Hi @norie, added the csv file i am using

Comment: data = csvone[csvone['IP Address'].str.contains(x)] < I get error from this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of digit-blocks - here 2 - you could use [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) in combination with [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) to do

```
result = (
    csvone
    .assign(IP=csvone["IP Address"].str.extract(r"^(\d+\.\d+\.)"))
    .merge(csvdata, on="IP", how="left")
    .drop(columns="IP")
)
```

or

```
result = csvone.merge(
    csvdata,
    left_on=csvone["IP Address"].str.extract(r"^(?P<IP>\d+\.\d+\.)")["IP"],
    right_on="IP",
    how="left"
).drop(columns="IP")
```

---

If the number of digit-blocks isn't fixed - last update - then it's a bit more trickier. One way would be to build an explicit pattern that takes the number of `.`s into account: IPs in `csvdata` with more `.`s should come before the ones with lesser `.`s. You could try

```
pat = "^(?P<IP>" + "|".join(
    ip.replace(".", r"\.")
    for ip in csvdata.IP.sort_values(
        key=lambda ser: ser.str.count("."), ascending=False
    )
) + ")"
```

to build a pattern like

```
^(?P<IP>10\.2\.100\.|10\.2\.120\.|10\.10\.|10\.20\.|10\.1\.|10\.3\.)
```

such that

```
result = csvone.merge(
    csvdata,
    left_on=csvone["IP Address"].str.extract(pat)["IP"], right_on="IP",
    how="left"
).drop(columns="IP")
```

produces the following output

```
      IP Address INFO LOCATION
0   10.1.100.123    a        A
1   10.1.100.125    b        A
2   10.2.120.128    c        C
3   10.2.100.130    d        B
4   10.3.100.150    e        D
5  10.10.200.168    f        E
6  10.20.180.199    g        F
```

PS: Actually, for your example data the ordering of the ips in the pattern doesn't matter. But if you would add, for example, `10.3.100` to the ips in `csvdata` then it would start to become relevant: `10.3.100` is more specific than `10.3.` and therefore has to be matched first.

Comment: Hi @Timur, the unhashable type error has been fixed by using your code.   However the outcome is not as what I expected. Seems like I am missing some code to link the IP and Location together.  You can refer the question for current outcome. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VoonEngHong See edit.

Comment: your code works great for 10.1, 10.2 etc.., but if I add another digit behind such as 10.20 or 10.10 it return wrong result... Is it possible to include the dot (.) in my csvdata? For example (10.1.) and (10.10.). I have tried but result is NaN. I also added the dataframe I am working on in the question as you suggested. Thanks for your help! @Timus

Comment: @VoonEngHong Thanks for the samples. See my edit: Does that work for you?

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for! What if I need to add more number on my IP column, I have tried `.assign(IP=csvone["IP Address"].str.extract(r"^(\d+\.\d+\.)")(r"^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)")) ` but it return with error code **ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1** I have updated the csv data on the question @Timus

Comment: @VoonEngHong I have added an alternative that might work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The variable x seems to be a pandas Series object. `pandas.DataFrame.str.contains()` requires the pattern (first argument) to be a string, not a series.

Check out examples in
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html